# How to send mail incase of test execution failure in Karate UI

Tags: karate

Am using Karate UI which is so helpful in many ways but now my need is to send email incase of any scenario's failed. It should trigger an email to my email id (from and to will be same my address for now)

Is there any documentation on the same I tried to get some insight around it but couldnt find one. Any help on this please

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is baked into the core karate framework, but you do have a couple options:

1. You could integrate your suite with a CI/CD tool like Jenkins and then use post-build actions or one of their email plugins to send the email from the CI/CD tool after the test suite has finished and detected failures.
2. You could write custom java code using the java interop feature that would allow you to handle email sending using something like SMTP library which you could then call from your feature files to generate and send the email.

Ultimately the best option depends on your project, specific needs and infrastructure you are willing to setup. CI/CD route would require more of a learning curve and added dependencies plus overhead to achieve but would give the most scalability and built-in features. The custom java route would have a more simplified setup on the front end but would probably have less functionality, be more cumbersome to invoke and less scalable.

Comment: Thank you so much. can you share some sample code that captures karate test failure console results and like mailing them that would be more helpful